# How to add Icon for your Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, icons, live, wallpaper

My live wallpaper has an Icon, it shows before you install it, but after you install it and you go to Wallpaper>Live Wallpaper, there is no icon in it, it's just an empty gray image. 
My live wallpaper has an Icon, it shows before you install it, but after you install it and you go to Wallpaper>Live Wallpaper, there is no icon in it, it's just an empty gray image.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:versionName="1.0" package="com.cutecats.cats" 
    android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />



    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service
            android:name=".CubeWallpaper1"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
            <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon">
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/cube1" />
        </service>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/cube2_settings"
            android:name=".CubeWallpaper1Settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of icons for live wallpaper from what i understand. Each shows in its own time, and what you are talking about is actually a thumbnail and needs to be placed inside

```
      <wallpaper>
```

tag. 
Here is how i did it: i created pony.xml file with following code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:thumbnail="@drawable/pony"
        android:description="@string/pony_desc"
     />
```

Inside manifest file i have following:

```
  <service android:label="@string/pony" android:name="my.pony.wallpaperManagement.SleepyPonyWallpaper"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
        android:resource="@xml/pony" />
  </service>
```

Note the reference to pony.xml.

Also, don't forget to have your icon in appropriate size (e.g. 64x64).

Comment: Too late probably, but if it helps someone else please let me now.